# startActivity throw NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchCancelPendingInputEvents(ViewGroup.java:3405)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchCancelPendingInputEvents(ViewGroup.java:3405)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchCancelPendingInputEvents(ViewGroup.java:3405)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchCancelPendingInputEvents(ViewGroup.java:3405)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchCancelPendingInputEvents(ViewGroup.java:3405)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchCancelPendingInputEvents(ViewGroup.java:3405)
at android.view.View.cancelPendingInputEvents(View.java:13591)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3554)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3493)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3735)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3703)
at com.example.mobile.dt.startActivity(PActivity.java:223)
at com.example.mobile.label.SplashActivity.d(SplashActivity.java:280)
at com.example.mobile.label.SplashActivity.b(SplashActivity.java:266)
at com.example.mobile.label.SplashActivity.c(SplashActivity.java:512)
at com.example.mobile.label.SplashActivity.b(SplashActivity.java:446)
at com.example.mobile.label.y.run(SplashActivity.java:388)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

I'm creating a BaseActivity that extending by ChildActivity.
When i'm trying to call startActivity(intent) its happening.

SplashActivity(Child)

```
public void openLoginActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, com.example.mobile.LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

And in BaseActivity

```
@Override
public void startActivity(Intent intent) {
    super.startActivity(intent);
}
```

this is the code that called at SplashActivity: 388 I'm calling StatusResponse(PResponse)

```
private void StatusResponse(Response response) { 
    JSONObject jsonResponse = response.response;
    if (jsonResponse == null) {
        restart();
        return;
    } else {

        try {
            openLoginActivity();
        } catch (JSONException ex) {
            restart();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Its throwing sometimes only. I'm not sure why its happening.

Some one help me!!!

Comment: why are you overriding startActivity?

Comment: Remove the package in your Intent declaration 
Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);

Comment: Are you using the `startActivity` in an own Thread?

Comment: But i'm using LoginActivity project as library in the childActivity project.

Comment: Can you show whats here: SplashActivity.java:388

Comment: Guys I tried without package declarations like only LoginActivity.class But its throwing sometimes only.

Comment: @mapo I updated my question with you asked.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating one Intent with first parameter `this`.
And just after you are deleting the activity.
I think the system can't find the value of the variable `this`.

You don't need to launch `finish()` after `startActivity()`.
The garbage collector removes unused variables after some time. This is why it is randomly failing.

EDIT :

My bad, I think you are currently using `response` without checking if he exist.
So add one `IF` like :

```
if (response != null) {
    JSONObject jsonResponse = response.response;
    // SOME CODE
}
```

Comment: The finish() we can call before startActivity. That doesn't matter about garbage collector.

Comment: if it was the unchecked response access, the call stack would look differently.